# Installing lubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, dependencies, lxde, 19.04

I'm wondering, what is the reccomended way to install LXDE alongside Ubuntu 19.04, while getting the full "Lubuntu" experience? I tried running the following command:

```
>$ sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop 
...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lubuntu-desktop : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: plasma-discover but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I know I can do `sudo apt install lxde`, but does that give everything that lubuntu-desktop has? Or will it just be a stripped-down default LXDE installation?

I tried doing and apt `update` and `dist-upgrade`, but it made no change.

Comment: Lubuntu last used LXDE in 18.04 LTS.   Lubuntu now use the LXQt desktop so `lubuntu-desktop`isn't trying to install the LXDE desktop at all.  Do you want Lubuntu (LXQt) or LXDE ?

Comment: @guiverc huh, I didn't not know the difference, I thought LxQt was just LXDE with a Qt backend. Do you know which is more lightweight? I probably want LxQt, if it's what lubuntu uses.

Comment: LXDE is a project on life-support (upstream now is the raspberry pi's PIXEL desktop); other devs moved to LXQt long ago.  LXQt started as Razor-Qt, so it's not just a back-end switch.  I'd suggest LXQt as LXDE gets little love.  As for your issue, I'd suggest `sudo apt -f install`, then try installing `lubuntu desktop ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt` (ie. tack on the packages it says it needs into same command).  I've had your issue twice last few months, but i forget what I did sorry.

Comment: **You first need to fix "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."** Lubuntu with LXQt is not as "light" as Lubuntu with LXDE but if you want the latest Lubuntu, it comes with LXQt by default. If you don't mind my saying so, I wouldn't install additional desktop environments unless I'm willing to learn by breaking stuff or I'm prepared for a bit of trouble-shooting.

Comment: @DKBose really? I've had KDE and Gnome installed side by side with no problem. How do I fix the broken packages?

Comment: Search Ask Ubuntu for "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages" and then sort by votes. As for your having no problem installing a second DE, that's great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as the [`lubuntu-desktop` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=lubuntu-desktop) is available from *universe* pocket.